# note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningInFunction’ and warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]

Tags: c++, openfoam

I am trying to convert a solver from older version of OpenFOAM to newer version. I made the required changes and code got compiled but it was not a clean compilation. I am getting a lot of warnings and notes like:

```
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C: In member function ‘Foam::label Foam::interpolation2DTable<Type>::Xi(const BinaryOp&, Foam::scalar, bool) const [with BinaryOp = Foam::lessOp<double>; Type = double]’:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:256:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     ::Foam::Warning((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
     ^
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:260:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningIn’
 #define WarningInFunction WarningIn(FUNCTION_NAME)
                           ^~~~~~~~~
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:251:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningInFunction’
                 WarningInFunction
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.H:170:0,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:39,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:256:13: note: here
             case interpolation2DTable::CLAMP:
             ^~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:51:0,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpaceI.H:26,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpace.H:226,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Vector.H:44,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/vector.H:39,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/fieldTypes.H:35,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvMatricesFwd.H:32,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvOption.H:47,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionOption.H:35,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionHeatTransferModel.H:41,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:37,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C: In member function ‘Foam::label Foam::interpolation2DTable<Type>::Xi(const BinaryOp&, Foam::scalar, bool) const [with BinaryOp = Foam::greaterOp<double>; Type = double]’:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:256:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     ::Foam::Warning((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
     ^
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:260:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningIn’
 #define WarningInFunction WarningIn(FUNCTION_NAME)
                           ^~~~~~~~~
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:251:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningInFunction’
                 WarningInFunction
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.H:170:0,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:39,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:256:13: note: here
             case interpolation2DTable::CLAMP:
             ^~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:51:0,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpaceI.H:26,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpace.H:226,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Vector.H:44,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/vector.H:39,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/fieldTypes.H:35,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvMatricesFwd.H:32,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvOption.H:47,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionOption.H:35,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionHeatTransferModel.H:41,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:37,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C: In member function ‘Type Foam::interpolation2DTable<Type>::interpolateValue(const Foam::List<Foam::Tuple2<double, Type> >&, Foam::scalar) const [with Type = double]’:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:256:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     ::Foam::Warning((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
     ^
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:260:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningIn’
 #define WarningInFunction WarningIn(FUNCTION_NAME)
                           ^~~~~~~~~
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:145:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningInFunction’
                 WarningInFunction
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.H:170:0,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:39,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:152:13: note: here
             case interpolation2DTable::CLAMP:
             ^~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:51:0,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpaceI.H:26,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpace.H:226,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Vector.H:44,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/vector.H:39,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/fieldTypes.H:35,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvMatricesFwd.H:32,
                 from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude/fvOption.H:47,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionOption.H:35,
                 from lnInclude/interRegionHeatTransferModel.H:41,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:37,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:256:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     ::Foam::Warning((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
     ^
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:260:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningIn’
 #define WarningInFunction WarningIn(FUNCTION_NAME)
                           ^~~~~~~~~
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:173:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘WarningInFunction’
                 WarningInFunction
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.H:170:0,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.H:39,
                 from sources/interRegion/interRegionHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer/tabulatedHeatTransfer.C:26:
/home/anjul/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/interpolation2DTable.C:180:13: note: here
             case interpolation2DTable::CLAMP:
```

How do I get rid of these warnings and more importantly, what do they mean? I tried looking up on the web but it's not helping.

Comment: Please also show your code. "May fall through" is probably related to the `case` of a `switch` missing a `break` (might be intended, thus it's only a warning)

Comment: It usually is best to focus on the first of several warnings/errors. Please provide a [mre] demosntrating the one you want to discuss.

Comment: I am converting old solver of OpenFOAM to newer version. It contains a lot of files and I have no idea where the error is coming. Is there any way to share the complete solver ? If yes, then I would be happy to do so and it will be easier for you to look into it.